# the meaning of Lenin's quote

Tags: meaning

What does this saying of Lenin mean: "The Capitalists will sell us the rope with which we will hang them"?

Comment: Use citations in your question, if you please. What has your search found? What do you think it means?

Comment: Even if Lenin had said this in English instead of Russian, I'd say your question is about understanding the political context rather than English language and usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard English saying, according to which you give someone “enough rope to hang himself”.  The idea is simple enough.  There are many people whose own vanity or other weaknesses will bring them to engineer their own downfall.  In such a case, better than confronting them, it might be better to leave them to it.

Lenin has wittily played on this idea.  Instead of the proletariat ***GIVING*** the capitalist the rope with which to hang ***himself***, the capitalist **SELLS** the proletariat the rope with which we can hang ***him*** (presumably in a revolution.

Comment: Excellent answer that points out the language conventions employed that contribute more to the irony well .